# Combine Akka Typed experimental with regular Akka(untyped)

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I've been reading about new experimental feature in Akka(http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/typed.html) and I'm curious if is there a way to gradually incorporate typed actors experimental API code into existing codebase(untyped akka), I mean combine both approaches at the same time?